# load a single flv file to flash via XML

Tags: xml, flash

I'm creating an SWF banner which calls an external FLV file. I was wondering if there's a way to load a single video via XML? The idea is that if I need to change the video being loaded, I can just change the filename from XML without touching the FLV files.

I only know basic action script and almost zero xml btw, but the client requested this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cfd.html

If you load your xml, you can have access to the path of the new flv and use it to load your video.

Here is also a tutorial: http://republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xmlvideoplayer/

If you have specific questions, let me know.